# How to render useQuery both on first render and onclick? [ReactJS, graphql]

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

How do I get my useQuery() to fire on both first render as well as on subsequent events (e.g. button click)?

From what I've read, when React mounts a component that calls a `useQuery` for the first time, Apollo automatically executes the query, and if I want to execute that query in response to an event, I can instead use `useLazyQuery` which returns a function that can be called. What if I want to do both?

Not very sure which part of my understanding of React hooks is incorrect or incomplete, but I've tried with using `refetch` in `useQuery`, which definitely allows me to call that function, but doesn't seem to always fire upon component mount (the more confusing thing is that sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't). I'm also using `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange`, which I read it needed for `refetch` to recognise that it should trigger the `onCompleted` part of the `useQuery`.

Any help would be much appreciated, I think I don't really understand Hooks at all. Thanks!

P.S. an example of my `useQuery` is as follows:

```
const { refetch: refetchGetTaskTypes } = useQuery(GET_TASK_TYPES(["taskId", "taskType"]), {
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    onCompleted: (data) => {
        if (data !== undefined && data.getTaskTypes !== undefined && data.getTaskTypes !== state.taskTypes) {
            dispatch({
                type: 'GET_TASK_TYPES',
                payload: {
                    taskTypes: data.getTaskTypes
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

P.P.S. as an example of `refetch` sometimes needing to be called to render and other times not, I have another `useQuery` that is almost identical to the above (with a different query) that also has `refetch`, but it renders on first load

P.P.P.S. I sometimes see another issue where `refetch` gets outdated data, and I have to use `fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'` to fix it. It doesn't always happen however

Comment: use useLazyQuery and then call it inside of a useEffect(()->{},[]) which will handle your initial load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use LazyQuery -

```
const [getTaskType, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_TASK_TYPE, {fetchPolicy: 'network-only'}); // fetch policy is to not look for cache and take the data from network only
```

To get the data on page load -

```
useEffect(() => {
    getTaskType();
}, []);
```

To anytime trigger it on button click you can simply call the method. -

```
<Button                                                
  onClick={()=>getTaskType()}>Click Me!
</Button>
```

Comment: thank you @Dlucidone! is this the recommended way? also, is it "against" any kind of react-hooks rules? as I understand that in hooks you don't really "call" the hooks per se

Answer (score 0):

> , but I've tried with using refetch in useQuery, which definitely allows me to call that function, but doesn't seem to always fire upon component mount (the more confusing thing is that sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't)

### I doubt

... network requests not fired? ... or your `onCompleted` conditions not met (no `dispatch` then)? No `dispatch` doesn't mean not requested/fired ...

```
onCompleted: (data) => {
    if (data !== undefined && data.getTaskTypes !== undefined && data.getTaskTypes !== state.taskTypes) {
```

### Probably you can remove all conditions:

- `onCompleted` is fired when `data` exists, no need to test it (`data !== undefined`)
- `getTaskTypes` is nullable? If not (IMHO it shouldn't), don't test it, either;
- `data.getTaskTypes !== state.taskTypes` - why don't ask API for this type only? Filtering not supported?

Your code is a bit confusing

```
useQuery(GET_TASK_TYPES(["taskId", "taskType"])
```

It looks like some generator/function (to define required fields?) - use const instead.

### Redux

It looks like you are using redux to store received data. Apollo is much smarter (normalizing cache) and doesn't need to write custom actions for each data [type] fetch. You should use Apollo for that but probably you tested it and failed? ...

### Missing `id` fields?

Your tasks doesn't have an `id` field but `taskId`? Apollo won't write it into cache. Luckily you can help Apollo to recognize unique identifiers in your data - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#custom-identifiers

After this you can simply use `data` from `useQuery` for 1st render and `refetch` on demand/from event handler (without using `useEffect` hook).

Comment: hi @xadm, thanks for your reply! I have checked my onCompleted (it doesn't even fire outside the if statement). What do you mean by "ask API for this type"? I'm using typescript if that matters, so I need to check the type manually (can't seem to compile otherwise). Also not sure what you mean by "use const"? Lastly, about using `data` and `refetch`, how do I update the `data` variable with `refetch`? I have tested and `data` doesn't seem to update with the info from a new query. Thanks!

Comment: sorry forgot to say: I'm not using Redux, I'm using the Apollo Store. I have a Store.tsx defined with the dispatch resolvers etc.!

Comment: you should not check onCompleted firing but RAW/JSON network requests/response in browser dev tools .... ask API to return only some task type (if more task types) ... if it is a typescript then you should use typed `useQuery` to define response data type, not check it by code ... `data` should be changed, again, check nertwork response ... Apollo store? docs/example?

Comment: I have checked the Network in my browser as well, the backend data is correct there, and `data` doesn't match it

Comment: IMHO you should use `{ fetchPolicy: "network-only" }` for this query

Comment: so sorry for all this, turned out to be a shallow copy vs. deep copy issue as I had a nested array of nested objects. But thanks a lot for all these tips! Hope to become more proficient at handling ReactJS and Hooks in particular over time :)