# React-query - refetch data when component mounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to refetch the data when the component mounts? At the moment with react-router if I navigate around my app it fetches the data once and then if I navigate away and come back the data is still the old one and not a new request?

I have not wrapped my fetch call in useEffect.

```
const fetchInfo = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/${id}`);
        return res.json();
    };

    const { data, status } = useQuery('tableInfo', fetchInfo, {
        staleTime: 5000,
    });
```

using as:

```
{status === 'error' && (
                <div className="mt-5">Error fetching data!</div>
            )}
            {status === 'loading' && (
                <div className="mt-5">Loading data ...
                   
                </div>
            )}
            {status === 'success' && (
                <div className="mt-5">
                    <p>Result will be here</p>
                </div>
            )}
```

Comment: Similar question is answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587993/how-to-render-usequery-both-on-first-render-and-onclick-reactjs-graphql

Answer (score 2):

With your setup, if you fetch your data, move to another view and come back (at least 5 seconds later) it will refetch - if you navigate and come back BEFORE those 5 seconds - it should not.

If you want to prevent re-fetching when you consider data not becoming stale over time (or not so quickly anyway), set `staleTime` to more than just 5 seconds  (up to `Infinity`)

If you want to re-fetch data on every navigation to that view - don't set `staleTime` at all

Comment: So I want the fetch data to recall when the component mounts and refresh the component?

Comment: In `react-query` data re-fetches after component mount by default (aka becomes "stale" right after it was fetched). To change it and tell `react-query` that your data is not becoming stale that fast (then it won't be re-fetched on every component render / view change), you should define `staleTime`.

Comment: so if I specify staletime, to what number?

Comment: It depends on your data in fact - if you don't expect it to change over user session lifetime - you may even go for `Infinity` (then you would have to mutate / refetch it manually). Otherwise, set it for amount which will prevent overfetching it (again, depends on data - it may be 1 minute as well as 15 minutes)

Comment: Although I think this is something to do with react-router rather than react-query

Comment: The request is happening when I navigate to the view but the view is not refreshing